# Django Rest Swagger 2.0: How to pass data to POST api so that I can get it as request.POST['key']

Tags: python-3.x, post, django-rest-framework, django-rest-swagger

I am trying to integrate `django-rest-swagger==2.1.1` to existing project which has function based views.

In order to add missing paramaters to function based views, I am using this solution:

[Solution by daimon](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger/issues/549#issuecomment-250145712)

I specify required parameters in yaml, which shows the field in swagger UI too. Now inside my view `request.POST['key']` gives `None`. But `request.body` contains the required parameter. How should I modify the swagger settings so that view becomes able to access data with `request.POST['key']`.

I have already tried [solution](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger/issues/50) but it didnt work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is actually with your parser, you ll have to mention parser classes in your `settings.py` priority wise, as mentioned by marcgibbon himself here:
[Click to see](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger/issues/588/#issuecomment-265593604)

Comment: That worked, i couldnt find it in the documentation, thanks